# what is the best practice to manage configurations(indexes, mapping, pipeline) for elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, architecture

I am adding an elasticsearch instance to our service(not ELK but only E) and trying to configure pipelines, indexes with some settings, and create some mapping. Initially, I thought the elasticsearch may provide a way to bootstrap from some files to create pipelines, indexes, or etc.. but I can't find a way to do it. I know I can create them on the fly through REST apis. But to do that, it looks like it needs another service instance to make sure that the elasticsearch is configured in the way our service needs.

So my questions are two folds. 
1. Is there a way to preconfigure pipelines, index with some settings and create mappings within elasticsearch instance?
2. If not, is it common to have another service that handles setting initial configuration to elasticsearch? and may be even query as well as a kind of proxy to elastic service? or maybe best pratices when you don't use any managed service?

PS. my questions may be too naive but I am pretty new to elasticsearch and even search server. Any helps would be welcome!

Comment: From my understanding. Logstash with Fielbeat helps you to set up the above things you mentioned  seamlessly

Comment: If you need help setting those up I can help